# Passing User attributes as a variable in Django Template

Tags: python, django

On my index page, I have the basic polls app index from the Django Official tutorial.

I am looking to include something along the lines of Hello, {{ user }} from {{ user.location }} on every page by including these variables in my base template.

{{ user }} renders properly, but there is nothing that shows up with {{ user.location }}, even though I have created a location attribute and filled it out using DjangoAdmin.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s's profile" % self.user
```

base.html

```
<h1>User is {{ user }} from {{ user.location }}</h1>
```

I am struggling with conceptualizing how to handle the view with passing the UserProfile, and how I would associate that to a base.html template (assuming I wanted to have this message show up on all pages).

Any help + tips/recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Well, what is the model of 'user' you mentioned in your template, User or UserProfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User and UserProfile are two different models. But since you have a `OneToOneField` from `UserProfile` to `User`, you can also follow it back.

```
<h1>User is {{ user }} from {{ user.userprofile.location }}</h1>
```

From the docs on [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)

> If you do not specify the related_name argument for the OneToOneField, Django will use the lower-case name of the current model as default value.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a benefit to defining a custom User model instead of creating a UserProfile model, as far as a simple application like this is concerned? I am trying to use django-registration-redux, and it seems like the easiest way to go about it is by using the standard User model.

Comment: Using a profile works fine, and until recently it was the only way to do it in Django. For your second or third django project it can be worth learning about custom user models.